# How to fix mongoose query that returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to query for records in my database but I am getting an empty array. I don't know what I am doing wrong? I have a feeling the issue could be my schema, here it is:

my schema

```
const QuizSchema = new Schema({

    question: {
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    answers: [{
        type: {
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
    }]
});

module.exports=Quiz=mongoose.model('quizes',QuizSchema,'quiz');
```

Here is the mongoose query

```
const Quiz = require('../../models/Quiz');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{

Quiz.find({},null)
.then(data=>res.json(data))
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
});
module.exports = router;
```

And here is a sample JSON data

```
{
        "question": "What is a Mongoose ? ",
        "answers": [
            { "type": "Smart","content": "Animal" }, {"type": "Subpar", "content": "Software"}, { "type": "Confused", "content": "Poem" }]

    }
```

Would appreciate your assistance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Shubh  Yes, i have tried without parameters, same empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<query>.then` doesn't return the data. You should use `<query>.exec().then` to access the data returned by the query. So change your code to something like:

```
Quiz.find({},null)
.exec()
.then(data=>res.json(data))
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
});
module.exports = router;
```

Source: [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)

Comment: @8SINS please add the logged response and the query you are using fetch the sample data.

Comment: router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    
Quiz.find({},null)
.exec()
.then(data=>res.json(data))
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
});              I am testing with postman, and the reponse is 200  oK but with an empty array

Comment: Your Solution was correct! I just found out my mistake... I wasn't querying the right DB. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Modify Schema like this: Inside the array, field name like 'type' is not accepted.

```
const QuizSchema = new Schema({

    question: {
        type:String,
        default:''
    },
    answers: [{
        ans_type: { // CHANGE HERE
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
        content: {
            type: String,
            default:''
        },
    }]
});

module.exports=Quiz=mongoose.model('quizes',QuizSchema,'quiz');
```